# How to enable WebCam in a browser?

Tags: webcam

My built-in WebCam on a Compaq 615 works in Skype and cheese, but doesn't work using a browser in chats like omegle.

I can't enable it. Clicking on the flash player option doesn't do anything.

How can I enable my WebCam on sites like that?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Next time, please use your [Shift] key for correct CaPiTaLiSaTiOn!  :-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? What browser are you using?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...